# Proving that the Large Deviations Function for the Chernoff Upper Bound is Continuous

Tags: probability, measure-theory, large-deviation-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable such that:

- $X$ is continuous with PDF $f_X$
- $X$ has a finite moment generating function $M_x(s) = \mathbb{E}[e^{sX}] < \infty$ for all $s \in \mathbb{R_+}$
- $X$ does not admit finite upper and lower bounds (i.e. $0 < F_X(x) < 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

How can I show that the large-deviations function,

$$\phi(a) = \sup_{s\geq 0} \{sa - \log(M(s))\}$$

is continuous for all $a \geq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

If you fix $s$, $sa-\log M(s)$ is a maximum of straight lines which is convex and by definition is continous. The function above is also known as the Fenchel-Lenegdre transform.

Comment: ...Except possibly at the boundaries of its domain.